# How to set unix carriage returns in .sh file in windows

Tags: docker-compose

I've been following along this quickstart guide:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/

Unfortunately I've come undone with this aspect:

> Note: Make sure to use UNIX line delimiters. The script doesn’t work
>   if you use Windows-based delimiters (Carriage return and line feed).

I've tried downloading and running dos2unix on my .sh file, and I've tried in notepad++ using the Edit > EOL Conversion - UNIX (LF) option.

But whenever I run my docker-composer up I get this:
[image]

I'm working on a windows machine.  My docker engine is running linux containers (as was default).  Hoping to get this quickstart working so I can get my head around it better as I'm not 100% sure of the issue but it seems related to these return characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give [vim editor](https://www.vim.org/download.php) a shot. Use `set ff=unix` to have `\n` as a line separator. You'll need vim anyway when you'll be editing linux configs inside your containers.
2. If you don't want to fix your editor, install sed (from cygwin or unixtools) and run this command to fix your text files:

```
sed 's/\r//g' entrypoint-crlf.sh > entrypoint.sh
```

3. To develop linux software it's better to have linux handy. You can run your next favorite editor (vim/emacs) in docker [too](https://hub.docker.com/r/jare/vim-bundle/).
4. Even better is to have a mac or linux desktop. It's so much easier to deal with linux containers when your desktop is unix-flavoured. Some people have a linux VM and do all development there accessing with ssh.